# Program crash when empty main function return

Tags: c++, qt

There is a qt project with an empty main function in linux system.

main.cpp:

```
int
main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

This qt project has other cpp files, but they are not called by the main function.

The strange thing is that when I run the program, the program crashes on return.

This is gdb information:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/user/test.out
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000031 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000031 in  ()
#1  0x00007ffff24db15e in __cxa_finalize (d=0x7ffff4d29000) at cxa_finalize.c:83
#2  0x00007ffff4bfe0e7 in __do_global_dtors_aux () at /lib/libdcmdata.so.13
#3  0x00007fffffffd780 in  ()
(gdb) l
1   int
2   main()
3   {
4       return 0;
5   }
```

When I exclude other cpp from the project, the program runs correctly. So I think it is those cpp files that caused the crash.

So my question is

How to find the cause of the crash in tens thousands lines of code?

What is the most likely cause of the crash?

How can I do?

If anyone can help, thank you very much!

Comment: global initialization/destruction...

Comment: Some objects are created before `main` starts, typically globals and sometimes `static` objects, and destructed after `main` ends.  (POD globals will be in a zero-initialized segment, and won't need to have a constructor or destructor called.)  This can lead to order of construction bugs, and order of destruction bugs.  Looks like one of your `*.cpp` files translation unit has such a global.  :-(

Comment: Do you compile without optimizations and with debugging info?